# Check if the element coresponds with a condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a script with the next logic:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

 document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = arr.map(item =>
   `<li > ${item}</li>`
 ).join(' ');
```

```html
<ul id="outer">

</ul>
```

When i will click on each `<li>` to check if it coresponds with the next condition `item>3`, and if the item is lower than 3 to hide the element. This scenario should be available for each element, so when i will click on another element to apply the idea above. I want to do this without  css classes. How it is possible? it is possible to apply here the method `filter()`?

Comment: Are you saying you want all items to be visible until you click, and when you click, if it's 3 or less, hide it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];
document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = arr.map(item =>
  `<li > ${item}</li>`
).join(' ');
document.querySelectorAll('#outer li').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(parseInt(e.target.textContent) < 3) {
      e.target.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="outer">

</ul>
```

Best practice would be to pass the item value to a `data` attribute rather than have it as text. See the example snippet below.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];
document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = arr.map(item =>
  `<li data-value="${item}">Element ${item}</li>`
).join(' ');
document.querySelectorAll('#outer li').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(parseInt(e.target.dataset.value) < 3) {
      e.target.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
list-style: none;
background: #cecece;
text-align: center;
padding: 1rem;
width: 10rem;
margin: 0 0 .25rem 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outer">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to get what you want but it doesn't involve any click handling, so I'm not sure if it satisfies your needs. The `filter` returns an array of all items for which the filter function returned something that evaluates as `true`. You can then use `map` on the resulting array to generate the list items. See below:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];

document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = 
  arr.filter(item => item > 3).map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join(' ');
```

```html
<ul id="outer">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8];
                
                let t = document.getElementById('outer').innerHTML = arr.map(item =>
                        
                        `<li > ${item}</li>`
                        
                ).join(' ');
                
                
                
                
                let elem = document.querySelectorAll('li');
                
                for (const elements of elem)
                
                elements.addEventListener("click",function() {
                        if(elements.innerHTML <3)
                        {
                                //remove the element
                                
                                elements.parentNode.removeChild(elements);
                                
                        }
                        //console.log(elements.innerHTML);
                        
                });
```

```html
                <ul id="outer">

</ul>
```

You could use the querySelectorAll to get all the

elements then check that the innerHTML is less than 3

Maybe this helps . when you click on a value lower than 3 it removes it from the DOM